# Are threads shared between different Dispatch queues?

Tags: ios, multithreading

Can a single thread be used in different dispatch queues?

I'm developing an app where i want to get a value depending on the thread where the code is running. For that i change the name of the thread when the block starts in a custom queue.

For example, if I add a block to mi custom queue, and i change the name of that thread to "SyncThread". Does a block called in a default system queue will be executed in that "SyncThread"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can a single thread be used in different dispatch queues?

Yes, and this is common. (The concept of "different dispatch queues" is itself problematic, since queues can, and do, target other queues. Seemingly simple questions like "what is the current queue" are not well defined.)

> I'm developing an app where i want to get a value depending on the thread where the code is running. For that i change the name of the thread when the block starts in a custom queue.

What you likely want for this is queue contextual data rather than thread-specific data (usually called thread-local storage). See `DispatchQueue.setSpecific(key:value:)`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i supposed that but i wanted to ask. What helped a lot was your mention of 'DispatchQueue.setSpecific(key:value:)'. With that i could done an approach to what i needed

Answer (score 1):

You use the terms *thread* and *queue* interchangeably but they aren't interchangeable; they're two distinct things. Apple doesn't want developers threading anymore, they want developers queueing their tasks. The queueing is handled by GCD which does all the threading behind the scenes. This means that two queues can certainly run on the same thread. And while all tasks within a queue run on distinct threads, not every task is guaranteed to run on the same thread, so keep that in mind. Therefore, I would take the advice given here to focus instead on queue context, not thread context.